# Heroku help rails app crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My Rails app crashs in Heroku when I run heroku open in git.
Here is my crash log: http://pastie.org/1686899

On my local pc I use Ruby version 1.9.2p136, Rails version 3.0.3 with phpmyadmin.
And when I run rails server all works fine.

Updated my new error log: http://pastie.org/1686947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the 1.8.6 stack. Run `heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2` and then deploy the application again.

if you still have an issue, please paste the error you get with the 1.9.2 stack.

#### edit

It looks like you're running a custom select like `konkurrancers".* FROM "konkurrancers" ORDER BY rand()`, at least the log says

> 2011-03-18T10:40:11-07:00 app[web.1]:
>   LINE 1: ...  "konkurrancers".* FROM
>   "konku rrancers" ORDER BY **rand()**
>   LIM... 2011-03-18T10:40:11-07:00
>   app[web.1]:

The problem is that rand() is not a function in postgress and that's why you're getting an error. (Heroku uses postgress as the DB engine)

#### Edit 2

try(I assume the name of the entity is Konkurrance)

```
Konkurrance.all[rand(Konkurrance.all.size)]
```

#### Edit 3

```
konkurrances = Konkurrance.find_all_by_kategori_id(@kategor)
@bannerkat = konkurrances[ rand(konkurrances.size) ]
```

and the next question is going to be €10 - I accept paypal :p

Comment: How do I rewrite the @banner = Konkurrancer.order('rand()').first to something postgress understand ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `ORDER BY rand()` in any db engine! Try Edit 2 approach instead. Generate a list of IDs in Ruby (length of your limit) and find them.

Comment: Why should I not use rand() ? It works fine with my mysql database

Comment: How do I rewrite this: @bannerkat = Konkurrancer.where("kategori_id = '#{@kategor}'").order('rand()').first

Comment: My solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database